# Load Folder of Scripts in R at startup?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and frankly the amount of documentation is overwhelming, and I haven't been able to find the answer to this question.

I have created a number of .R script files, all stored in a folder that I can access on my server (let's say the folder is, using the Windows backslash character \\servername\Paige\myscripts)

I know that in R you can call each script individually, for example (using the forward slash required in R)

```
source(file="//servername/Paige/myscripts/con_mdb.r")
```

and now this script, con_mdb, is available for use.

If I want to make all the scripts in this folder available at startup, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Briefly:

1. Use your `~/.Rprofile` in the directory found via `Sys.getenv("HOME")` (or if that fails, in R's own `Rprofile.site`)
2. Loop over the contents of the directory via `dir()` or `list.files()`.
3. Source each file.

as eg via this one liner

```
sapply(dir("//servername/Paige/myscripts/", "*.r"), source)
```

**but** the real story is that you should *not* do this.  Create a package instead, and load that.  Bazillion other questions here on how to build a package.  Research it -- it is worth it.

Comment: Sorry, no one to point out any mistakes in R or regex. You are the boss. But shouldn't `"*.r"` be `"*.r$"`?

Comment: You can,  but you don't have to.  I actually tested this before posting.  Did you?  :-P

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Great answer!  On the comment...what you said surprised me and I did `dir.create('temp');lapply(c('myscript.r', 'not.really.txt'), function(x) cat('', file=file.path('temp', x)));dir('temp', '*.r')` and both `'myscript.r` & `not.really.txt` were matched.  By your comment I thought you meant only the former would be matched.  But maybe that's not what you were saying.

Comment: The directory I tested worked with the expression I had.  So if confronted with a messier directory with files to be excluded, either the regexp can be tightened as suggested by @user2007598 and Tyler -- or a whole new filter step gets added.  The _more important takeaway_ is that we can in fact read the directory content on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Far the best way is to create a package! But as first step, you could also create one r script file (`collection.r`) in your script directory which includes all the scripts in a relative manner.

In your separate project scripts you can than include only that script with

```
source(file="//servername/Paige/myscripts/collection.r", chdir = TRUE)
```

which changes the directory before sourcing. Therefore you would have only to include one file for each project.

In the collection file you could use a loop over all files (except `collection.r`) or simply list them all.

Comment: I like the idea! What does "includes all the scripts in a relative manner" mean? Is it simply appending the scripts in a single file? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: This more or less shadows what I wrote earlier but omits the directory reading.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, you are right, its basically what you have written. But if its something like a library the import of all the files can be done in a single line in each project file. In a relative manner means that in `collection.r` you can import the other files with for example `source(file="./con_mdb.r")`. So the library (better your script files) do not have to know where they are located.

Comment: Actually,  it is not even an answer.  OP knew how to source each file one by one.  Now you're just saying _don't do that source one file which then sources all_ so you're just kicking the can down the road.  But we both agree on a package being preferable.

Comment: I'm sorry. My intuition said that his problem is more in structuring his scripts, rather than the asked sourcing.